# Oracle: Package created with compilation error when package contains function

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, package

I am using Oracle 10g express edition.

Here is my package creating code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ticketBooking 
   AS 
      FUNCTION maxOrderID() RETURN NUMBER; 
      FUNCTION maxTransactionID() RETURN NUMBER;
      PROCEDURE bookOrder(id IN NUMBER, key IN VARCHAR2, fname IN VARCHAR2, lname IN VARCHAR2, age IN NUMBER, address IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, status OUT NUMBER);
      PROCEDURE bookTicket(id IN NUMBER, orderID IN NUMBER, mID IN NUMBER, mRow IN NUMBER, mSeat IN NUMBER, mDate IN VARCHAR2, mTime IN NUMBER);
   END ticketBooking; 
/
```

This is giving the warning message:-

> Package created with compilation error.

When I am removing the two functions, then I am not getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Is it because there is no parameters passed in the two function? I don't need to send any parameter. What should I do?

Comment: If you do `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view, you can see what the actual compilation errors are.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use parentheses with zero param functions.

Try this:

```
create or replace PACKAGE ticketBooking 
   AS 
      FUNCTION maxOrderID RETURN NUMBER; 
      FUNCTION maxTransactionID RETURN NUMBER;
      PROCEDURE bookOrder(id IN NUMBER, key IN VARCHAR2, fname IN VARCHAR2, lname IN VARCHAR2, age IN NUMBER, address IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, status OUT NUMBER);
      PROCEDURE bookTicket(id IN NUMBER, orderID IN NUMBER, mID IN NUMBER, mRow IN NUMBER, mSeat IN NUMBER, mDate IN VARCHAR2, mTime IN NUMBER);
   END ticketBooking; 
 /
```

Comment: Shit! Didn't know that. Thanks Sir. :)